# How can I optimize this MySQL code?

Tags: mysql, optimization

The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentid` smallint(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parentid` (`parentid`,`category`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `parentid`, `category`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'A'),
(2, NULL, 'B'),
(3, 1, 'A.1'),
(4, 1, 'A.2'),
(5, 1, 'A.3'),
(6, 1, 'A.4'),
(7, 3, 'A.1.1'),
(8, 3, 'A.1.2'),
(9, 3, 'A.1.3');
```

The code, "callcategorycount" function is call the "categorycount" procedure for usable in select statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION callcategorycount(id SMALLINT(4)) RETURNS SMALLINT(4) BEGIN
    CALL categorycount(id, @categorycount);
    RETURN @categorycount;
END$$

CREATE PROCEDURE categorycount(IN categoryid SMALLINT(4), OUT categorycount SMALLINT(4)) BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS results;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp2;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 AS
        SELECT DISTINCT id, parentid FROM categories WHERE parentid = categoryid;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results AS
        SELECT id, parentid FROM temp1;

    WHILE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp1 ) DO
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 AS
            SELECT DISTINCT id, parentid FROM categories WHERE parentid IN (SELECT id FROM temp1);

        INSERT INTO results SELECT id, parentid FROM temp2;
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;

        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 AS
            SELECT id, parentid FROM temp2;

        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp2;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO categorycount FROM results;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS results;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

For output (Execution time: 1.7886 sec.):

```
SELECT id, parentid, category, callcategorycount(id) AS subcategories FROM categories;

|id|parentid|category|subcategories
|1|NULL|A|7
|2|NULL|B|0
|3|1|A.1|3
|4|1|A.2|0
|5|1|A.3|0
|6|1|A.4|0
|7|3|A.1.1|0
|8|3|A.1.2|0
|9|3|A.1.3|0
```

How to optimize "categorycount" procedure?

Comment: can't you use this with simple query instead of procedure?

Comment: like that?

select 
  parent.id, parent.category, count(child.id) 'number of children' 
from
  categories parent left join categories child
    on child.parentid = parent.id
group by parent.id
order by parent.id;

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: the above code only one level calculating number of children. I want to calculate multi level number of children. for example: A (have 2 children), A.A (have 1 children), A.A.A (have not any child)

Comment: you question is unclear how can you say that A has 2 children when A has 4. Parnetid 1 exists in 4 records

Comment: sorry, the example in my comment is different from my question.. and you say not correct, because A has 7 children in my question. parentid 1 exists in 4 records and parentid 3 exitst in 3 records. that all 7 records in A.

Comment: so it means A has 4 children and A.1 has 3?

Comment: yes, now I want to show A has 7 children

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: The database have only "categories" table. All columns in that table are have index:

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parentid` (`parentid`,`category`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
      T2.*,
      IFNULL(c.SubCount,0) as SUBCAOUNT
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parentid FROM categories WHERE id = _id) AS parentid,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 9, @l := 0) vars,
        categories m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN categories T2
ON T1._id = T2.id
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                COUNT(id) as SubCount, 
                parentid 
            FROM categories
            GROUP BY parentid) as c ON c.parentid = T1._id
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC;
```

In this query i am using 9 as parameter as it is the final depth of A.

Output

```
ID  PARENTID    CATEGORY    SUBCAOUNT
1   (null)      A           4
3   1           A.1         3
9   3           A.1.3       0
```

### SQL FIDDLE DEMO

EDITS:
Try this query.

```
SELECT 
      T2.*,
      SUM(c.SubCount) as SUBCAOUNT
FROM (
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := parentid FROM categories WHERE id = _id) AS parentid,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := 9, @l := 0) vars,
        categories m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN categories T2
ON T1._id = T2.id
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                IFNULL(COUNT(id),0) as SubCount, 
                parentid 
            FROM categories
            GROUP BY parentid) as c ON c.parentid = T1._id

ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC;
```

OUTPUT

```
ID  PARENTID    CATEGORY    SUBCAOUNT
9   3           A.1.3       7
```

### Demo

**MORE EDITS**

Here is How You can do it

```
SELECT
      c.id,
      c.category,
      IFNULL(Total,0) as No_Of_Children
FROM categories as c
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                 id,
                 COUNT(parentid) as Total,
                 parentid
            FROM categories
            GROUP BY parentid
) as lc ON lc.parentid = c.id;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  CATEGORY    NO_OF_CHILDREN
1   A           4
2   B           0
3   A.1         3
4   A.2         0
5   A.3         0
6   A.4         0
7   A.1.1       0
8   A.1.2       0
9   A.1.3       0
```

And Here is 

### Demo

Comment: I see A.1 category has 3 subcount, this is correct. but I see A category 4 subcount. this is not correct. I want to see 7 subcount for A category

Comment: I want to see this output: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb53a/28/0)  the A category's number of children is 4. but, I want see 7. can you update your code for this

Comment: okey, now I want to see 7 for the A category's no of children

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following although I suggest you double check my logic as it was done quickly.

**Add a counter field to the categories table**

```
-- TABLE

drop table if exists categories;
create table categories
(
cat_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment,
name varchar(255) not null,
parent_cat_id smallint unsigned null,
child_counter smallint unsigned not null default 0,
primary key categories_pk (cat_id),
key categories_parent_idx (parent_cat_id)
)
engine = innodb;
```

**Create a stored procedure for inserting categories**

```
-- SPROCS

drop procedure if exists insert_category;
delimiter #

create procedure insert_category
(
in p_name varchar(255),
in p_parent_cat_id smallint unsigned
)
proc_main:begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;

  insert into categories (name, parent_cat_id) values (p_name, p_parent_cat_id);

  if p_parent_cat_id is null then
    leave proc_main;
  end if;

  -- work out the parents

  create temporary table hier(
    parent_cat_id smallint unsigned, 
    cat_id smallint unsigned, 
    depth smallint unsigned default 0
  )engine = memory;

  insert into hier select parent_cat_id, cat_id, v_depth from categories where cat_id = p_parent_cat_id;

  /* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

  create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

  while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from categories c
        inner join tmp on c.cat_id = tmp.parent_cat_id and tmp.depth = v_depth) then

        insert into hier 
            select c.parent_cat_id, c.cat_id, v_depth + 1 from categories c
            inner join tmp on c.cat_id = tmp.parent_cat_id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

        set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

  end while;

  -- update parent counts

  update categories c
  inner join hier h on c.cat_id = h.cat_id
  set
   c.child_counter = c.child_counter + 1;

  drop temporary table if exists hier;
  drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end proc_main #

delimiter ;
```

**Testing and Results**

```
truncate table categories;

call insert_category('A',null); -- 1
call insert_category('B',null);

select * from categories;
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| cat_id | name | parent_cat_id | child_counter |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A    |          NULL |             0 |
|      2 | B    |          NULL |             0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

call insert_category('C',1); -- 3
call insert_category('D',1);
call insert_category('E',1); -- 5
call insert_category('F',1);

select * from categories;
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| cat_id | name | parent_cat_id | child_counter |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A    |          NULL |             4 |
|      2 | B    |          NULL |             0 |
|      3 | C    |             1 |             0 |
|      4 | D    |             1 |             0 |
|      5 | E    |             1 |             0 |
|      6 | F    |             1 |             0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

call insert_category('G',3); -- 7
call insert_category('H',3);
call insert_category('I',3); -- 9

select * from categories;
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| cat_id | name | parent_cat_id | child_counter |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A    |          NULL |             7 |
|      2 | B    |          NULL |             0 |
|      3 | C    |             1 |             3 |
|      4 | D    |             1 |             0 |
|      5 | E    |             1 |             0 |
|      6 | F    |             1 |             0 |
|      7 | G    |             3 |             0 |
|      8 | H    |             3 |             0 |
|      9 | I    |             3 |             0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Additional testing**

```
call insert_category('K',7); -- 10

select * from categories;
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| cat_id | name | parent_cat_id | child_counter |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A    |          NULL |             8 |
|      2 | B    |          NULL |             0 |
|      3 | C    |             1 |             4 |
|      4 | D    |             1 |             0 |
|      5 | E    |             1 |             0 |
|      6 | F    |             1 |             0 |
|      7 | G    |             3 |             1 |
|      8 | H    |             3 |             0 |
|      9 | I    |             3 |             0 |
|     10 | K    |             7 |             0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

call insert_category('L',9); 
call insert_category('M',10); 

select * from categories;
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| cat_id | name | parent_cat_id | child_counter |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A    |          NULL |            10 |
|      2 | B    |          NULL |             0 |
|      3 | C    |             1 |             6 |
|      4 | D    |             1 |             0 |
|      5 | E    |             1 |             0 |
|      6 | F    |             1 |             0 |
|      7 | G    |             3 |             2 |
|      8 | H    |             3 |             0 |
|      9 | I    |             3 |             1 |
|     10 | K    |             7 |             1 |
|     11 | L    |             9 |             0 |
|     12 | M    |            10 |             0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

call insert_category('N',7); 

select * from categories;
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| cat_id | name | parent_cat_id | child_counter |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A    |          NULL |            11 |
|      2 | B    |          NULL |             0 |
|      3 | C    |             1 |             7 |
|      4 | D    |             1 |             0 |
|      5 | E    |             1 |             0 |
|      6 | F    |             1 |             0 |
|      7 | G    |             3 |             3 |
|      8 | H    |             3 |             0 |
|      9 | I    |             3 |             1 |
|     10 | K    |             7 |             1 |
|     11 | L    |             9 |             0 |
|     12 | M    |            10 |             0 |
|     13 | N    |             7 |             0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)


call insert_category('O',5); 

select * from categories;
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
| cat_id | name | parent_cat_id | child_counter |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | A    |          NULL |            12 |
|      2 | B    |          NULL |             0 |
|      3 | C    |             1 |             7 |
|      4 | D    |             1 |             0 |
|      5 | E    |             1 |             1 |
|      6 | F    |             1 |             0 |
|      7 | G    |             3 |             3 |
|      8 | H    |             3 |             0 |
|      9 | I    |             3 |             1 |
|     10 | K    |             7 |             1 |
|     11 | L    |             9 |             0 |
|     12 | M    |            10 |             0 |
|     13 | N    |             7 |             0 |
|     14 | O    |             5 |             0 |
+--------+------+---------------+---------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Full script here: http://pastie.org/5649953

Hope it helps or points you towards an optimal solution.

Comment: I will try this technique with triggers. But now I think, how to update child_counter field when if I want to delete a row.

Comment: You'd minus 1 instead - you'd be better off with sprocs over triggers though imo :)